# How can I optimize in Pyomo with gradient-free optimization?

Tags: json, pyomo, nonlinear-optimization, black-box

I have a program (an external simulation) that receives a JSON file as input called input.json, does the simulation process as a black box (I do not have access) and gives as return a JSON file as output.json. The output file is used to calculate some parameters that compose an objective function. I am trying to use Pyomo to optimize this problem, however, it seems that it is not able to recognize any gradient in the function because of the transfer of information between the input and output files. I was thinking about a gradient-free optimization that surely will take more time but at least can have a good result.

I tried using Mindtpy but it was not able to find an optimum path to decrease the variable or variables.

Comment: Pyomo expects a model (an objective with a set of constraints and their functional form). What you describe is a black-box problem. That does not fit Pyomo and requires a black-box solver (these are indeed derivative-free solvers, and don't even require a functional form for the model). Black-box problems are very difficult. Often we split the problem in two: (1) use a statistical technique to fit a response surface and (2) optimize this fitted model. The (2) part you can do in Pyomo. Of course, this requires formulating a mathematical model based on some domain knowledge.

Comment: Thanks very much. I've tried with some Black-box optimization solvers and it seems is working. Do you have one recommended? As most of them are not well documented.

Comment: See: Rios, L.M., Sahinidis, N.V. Derivative-free optimization: a review of algorithms and comparison of software implementations. J Glob Optim 56, 1247–1293 (2013)